# Material Design 3 (MD3) color codes for specific color-tone

Tags: colors, material-design

There is [Material Theme Builder](https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom) which generates an MD3 palette, but it don't provides color codes for surface containers (e.g. N-96, N-94, N-92, etc.), where i can find color codes for them?